# Grammar: 'dangerous to' or 'dangerous for'

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Looking at the health warning on our beers, I'm sure the grammar is incorrect.

> "Alcohol abuse is dangerous **to** your health."

Shouldn't that be:

> "Alcohol abuse is dangerous **for** your health."

Used as a verb, we'd say: "This is **a danger to** you."

Used as an adjective shouldn't we say: "This is **dangerous for** you"?

Comment: Personally I think using *dangerous* as a modifier for "your health* is a bit odd. I'd prefer *bad for your health*, or (a bit more formal, perhaps) *injurious/harmful to [your] health*.

Comment: When something is dangerous to or for our health, using *to* will give a more direct impact, and that's probably why *to* is prominent in [this Google Ngram chart](http://goo.gl/NjKxUj).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both prepositions are correct with **dangerous**. You are restricted to use **for**  when you continue the sentence with a to-infinitive clause:

*It would be dangerous **for** you **to** stay here*.

*This is a danger to you*: This sentence doesn't use **danger** as a verb, but as a noun. This example is also correct.

Comment: And *a danger for you* would also be correct.

Comment: @PeterShor: Absolutely. I wrote the sentence as OP gave it to point out that "danger" isn't a verb here.

Answer (score 1):

Both 'dangerous for' and 'dangerous to' are correct.This has been mentioned in Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English.Even as a noun both 'danger to' and 'danger for' are correct although most prefer to use 'danger to'. Both of them  have been proved correct by rigorous and thorough analysis of British National Corpus, Corpus of American Contemporary English and Google Books Corpora.